# Resolving Absolute Import Conflicts

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Say I have a local file called "util.ts". With absolute imports enabled, I'm able to call everywhere in my app.

```
import * as util from 'util'
```

Now say theres a package named `util` in `node_modules`. That will be imported instead. Is there anyway to specify that I explicitly want my module rather than the one in node modules?

Comment: `from './util'`

Comment: This doesn't work if you're outside of the root directory.

Comment: Your import only works if `util` is a package: Bare specifiers like 'some-package' refer to an entry point of a package by the package name. My guess: Move `util.js` to `util/index.js` and add a `package.json` to the `util` folder.

Answer (score 1):

reference: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7795

Try

```json
{
  "compilerOptions":  {
    ...    
    "baseUrl": "."
  }
}
```

and prefix your imports with "src/", as in "src/util".

I encountered the exact some problem with wanting to use a file in my src directory named 'util.ts'. However, it turns out that node modules always win in cases of a name collision. The github issue link above references one possible solution, change your tsconfig baseUrl to '.' and for your absolute imports, prefix them with 'src', so 'src/util'.

I suspect you can use tsconfig 'paths' to alias things or avoid having to type src in other instances, but I haven't explored that route much as I actually am ok with prefixing my absolute imports with 'src'.

Paths reference: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths

Answer (score 0):

Have the import go to the files path instead
import * as util from "/main/utilities/util.js" - Example